# Как создать 2 итерации цикла в django?

Tags: python, html, django

Скажите пожалуйста как в шаблоне запустить 2 итерации одновременно,
во views - написал

```py
def gallery(request):
    images = [{'title': 'Изображение 1', 'url': 'image1.jpg'}, {'title': 'Изображение 2', 'url': 'image2.jpg'},
              {'title': 'Изображение 3', 'url': 'image3.jpg'}, {'title': 'Изображение 4', 'url': 'image4.jpg'}, ]
    classes = ['col-md-3 port-1-left', 'col-md-3 port-1-right', 'col-md-3 portfolio-right',
                'col-md-3 port-1-right portfolio-last']
    context = {'images_classes': zip(images, classes)}
    return render(
        request,
        'index.html',
        context=context
    )
```

Пытаюсь в шаблоне вывести

```html
{% for image, class_name in images_classes %}
  <div class="{{ class_name }}">
    <div class="portfolio app mix_all" data-cat="app" style="display: inline-block; opacity: 1;">
      <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
        <a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image.url }}" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go swipebox" title="">
          <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image.url }}">
          <div class="b-wrapper">
            <h2 class="b-animate b-from-left prt-1 b-delay03 ">{{ image.title }}</h2>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

реакции 0

Comment: Вы имеете в виду один цикл для двух переменных?

Comment: Мой знакомый телепат подсказывает — импортировать itertools и в context заменить `'images_classes': zip(images, itertools.cycle(classses))`

Comment: Тоже самое что и раньше, пробую через print - вывести значение context - получаю
[13/Jan/2023 16:53:31] "GET /birds/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5794